# infinite product of $\prod_{k=0}^\infty(I_2-A_k)$, where $A_k\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, infinite-product

Let $G_1,G_2\in\mathbb{C}$, such that ${\rm Re~}G_1G_2^*>0$. Let $a,\theta>0$. Assume $\cos\theta\neq0$ and $\sin\theta\neq0$. I need to show that for sufficiently small $a$,
\begin{equation}
\prod_{k=0}^\infty\left(I_2-a\begin{bmatrix}(\cos k\theta)^2&\cos k\theta\sin k\theta\\\cos k\theta\sin k\theta&(\sin k\theta)^2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{\rm Re~}G_1G_2^*&{\rm Im~}G_1G_2^*\\{\rm -Im~}G_1G_2^*&{\rm Re~}G_1G_2^*\end{bmatrix}\right)=0.
\end{equation}

I figured out that the condition ${\rm Re~}G_1G_2^*>0$ is equivalent to $|\angle(G_1/G_2)|<\pi/2$ (that is, $G_1$ is within 90$^\circ$ of $G_2$ in complex plane), but I have no idea how to proceed. Any idea or hint is appreciated. Thanks

Note: $I_2$ denotes identity matrix of dimension 2 and $^*$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose

Comment: Are you certain you've stated the problem correctly? It seems to me that taking $a$ small would tend to make the product _nonzero_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes I am. I also double-checked using numerical examples.